# Which characters should be escaped in Localizable.strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, localization

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH6-97055-CJBFDJGF) states the followings about the value of a key.

> Default value strings may contain extended ASCII characters.
>
> ...
>
> Just as in C, some characters must be prefixed with a backslash before you can include them in the string. These characters include double quotation marks, the backslash character itself, and special control characters such as linefeed (\n) and carriage returns (\r).

In my experience it did't matter if I used `'` or `\'`, after calling the `localizedStringForKey:value:table:` method the result was the same.

1. question: *why*?
2. question: is there an explicit list somewhere which lists all the characters which **must** be escaped and which *can* be (meaning that the result will be the same)?

Comment: `'` is a *single* quotation mark, that need not be escaped.

Comment: It doesn't *need* to be escaped, but it *can* be with the same result? (We'd like to use common resources with Android where single quotation marks must be escaped.)

Comment: Unfortunately, you will not be able to use common resources between the two. For Android you will need to escape the single quotes while escaping single quotes in iOS strings will result in a backslash in the UI. For iOS strings, you need to escape double quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the majority of cases we are able to use common resources, we only have to make a few exceptions like this one for example. (That is the reason I would've loved to see a reference which contains all the escapable characters.)